# No token found for audience https://storage.azure.com/

Tags: azure, azure-storage, terraform

Deploying Azure storage accounts with Terraform always ends up in error:

```
azurerm_storage_account.testsa: Creating...
azurerm_storage_account.testsa: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
azurerm_storage_account.testsa: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
azurerm_storage_account.testsa: Still creating... [30s elapsed]
azurerm_storage_account.testsa: Still creating... [40s elapsed]
azurerm_storage_account.testsa: Still creating... [50s elapsed]

Error: Error reading queue properties for AzureRM Storage Account "storageaccountname00002": azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://storageaccountname00002.queue.core.windows.net?comp=properties&restype=service: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'. Response body: {"error":{"code":"invalid_request","message":"No token found for audience https://storage.azure.com/"}}
```

Running the creation with the AZ cli works just fine and returns successful in under 30 seconds. 
Terraform version is latest one, v0.12.6

test.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "testrg" {
  name     = "resourceGroupName"
  location = "westus"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "testsa" {
  name                     = "storageaccountname00002"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.testrg.name}"
  location                 = "westus"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "GRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Comment: downgrading the azurerm provider to 1.31.0 seems to have fixed it, as per https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3997

Comment: Pleae post your comment as an answer, it can help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the same code with the Terraform v0.12.6+ provider.azurerm v**1.32.1**. It works well. I am [authenticating Azure Provider is using a Service Principal with a Client Secret.](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/service_principal_client_certificate.html) It looks like an authentication issue on your side. Authenticating via the Azure CLI is only supported when using **a User Account**. please see [important Notes about Authenticating using the Azure CLI](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/azure_cli.html#important-notes-about-authenticating-using-the-azure-cli).

[image]

Comment: that could also be it. I'm using a regular account for automation purposes, but since it's working with the other provider, I'm not going to change it now. will accept yours, thanks